# Difference between flattrs and flattrs_user_count

Tags: flattr

Looking at the [flattr API](http://developers.flattr.net/api/resources/things/) pages I see that `things` have both a `flattrs` and a `flattrs_user_count` field, but I'm not sure what the difference between them is, since you can only flattr a thing once.

So, what is the difference between the two fields?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm pretty sure you can flattr `things` multiple times, but only *once a month*, so the counts could in theory be drifting apart over time especially for things that many people are subscribed to (see [shownot.es](https://flattr.com/thing/874771/shownot-es) for example).